# Reading file contents and Deleting specific lines using parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

```
Class Student
{
   Int studentId,
   List<ClassB> Books,
   Boolean IsPassed
}

Class Book
{
    Int  bookId,
    List<int> pages
}
```

Here i store the book data in the disk physically.

```
BookID1 (Folder Name)

pageNumber1.txt
pageNumber2.txt
pageNumber3.txt
pageNumber4.txt


BookID2 (Folder Name)

pageNumber1.txt
pageNumber2.txt
pageNumber30.txt
pageNumber45.txt
```

From my database i will return some thing like this

```
StudentId         bookId.      Page     IsPassed
1                    1      1,2,3,4      1  
1.                   2      1,2,30,45    1
```

I will put them into dictionary as below

```
Key = bookId
Value = pages

Dictionary<long, List<int>> inputDictionary
```

How to read the data from corresponding pages in parallel and deleting some lines by line number without using multiple for loops
I tried this. Please let me know if there is any better option?

```
Parallel.ForEach
( 
   inputDictionary
   ,new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }
   , Book =>
  {
    foreach( int pagenumber in Book.Value)
    {
    var bookId = Book.Key.ToString();
    var PathToPage =  GetDisKPath()+bookId+pagenumber+".txt";
    }
    // read the file and delete some lines from page number.
  });
```

Comment: Instead of `List<int>` you'd better use `ConcurrentBag<int>` if you're going to remove values from it in parallel. List isn't threadsafe

Comment: Yeah Sure will consider that. Also i would like to know whether the approach itself can be optimized

Answer (score 0):

the way i undestand your code, you are not going to modify your inputDictionary in any way (just remove line from the text file on the disk ). in this case you can stick with your code which will work fine, if not you should use ConcurrentBag which is thread safe.

Another approach for the first case, is to use a regular for loop and use async io methods for reading and writing the files.

async io operations are different from cpu-bound async operations in that they don't spawn threads to execute, this can't speed up your app by reducing thread switching overhead.

head over to these pages for more info on sync programming and async io operation:
[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Asynchronous File I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am thinking of scenario where there are 50 books. Will my approach fits fine or need to change ?

Comment: I don't see the number of the books as particularly influencing. 
You should try with the async io  calls and see if it yields better performance.